# How to include value label in fusion chart column graph

Tags: xml, fusioncharts

I created a multi (3)series fusionchart, that compares various outputs for each month. due to the closeness of the 3series chart, their values are overlapping each other, making the graph look untidy. I was wondering if there is an attribute that can make me embed the values in bar column in a vertical position. I know such could be twicked from the properties of the `<graph>` attribute but I have not been able to get the exact one. I am populating the graph from a set of written array

```
 <graph caption='Generation Report Chart for 2014' xAxisName='Month'   yAxisName='Mega Watt'
      showValues='1' rotateValues= '1' numberSuffix='MW' decimalPrecision='0'    bgcolor='F3f3f3' bgAlpha='70' yaxismaxvalue='5000'
      showColumnShadow='1' divlinecolor='c5c5c5' divLineAlpha='60'   showAlternateHGridColor='1' 
  alternateHGridColor='f8f8f8' alternateHGridAlpha='60' formatNumberScale='0' >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the complete data for us to understand how they are overlapping, then only we might be able to help you out. I am not sure what you meant by `embedding` the values. From your code snippet you have already rotated your values. If you want to place your values inside the bar / columns; consider using `placeValueInside` and then use `valuePadding` to push them further inward.

If this is not what you want. Please elaborate or share a fiddle.